# Create new form by method

Tags: c#, forms, variables, methods

```
    public void IsOpen(Form f)
    {
        bool open = false;
        FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
        foreach (Form form in fc)
        {
            if (form == f)
            {
                if (form.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                {
                    form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                }
                form.BringToFront();
                open = true;
            }
        }
        if (open == false)
        {
            f = new Form();
            f.Show();
        }
    }
```

So i've got this bit of code here. It's meant to check the open forms in the application and determine if a form is already open. Now i'm using this because there's a couple of forms I don't want opened twice at the same time. My issue being is that I can't open the type of form that i want. I want to get the formtype of F and open the form of that specific type. Ex:

```
    private void mnuSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Settings set = new Settings();
        IsOpen(set);
    }
```

So i pass the form here, so f should equal the settings form. But I need the method to dynamically open different forms. So say I use Form1 instead of settings, I need to open an instance of Form1 if it's not open. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `It's meant to check the open forms in the application and determine if a form is already open.`  Uhm.. you don't even know what your own function does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Dictionary<Type, Form> forms = new Dictionary<Type, Form>();

public void OpenSingletonForm<T>() where T : Form, new() {
  if (!forms.ContainsKey(typeof(T)) {
    forms.Add(typeof(T), new T());
  }
  forms[typeof(T)].Show();
}
```

And use it like so:

```
OpenSingletonForm<SettingsDialog>();
```

Comment: Hmm, I seem to be unable to add a new form to the dictionary. It gives an error "Cannot create and instance of the variable T because it does not have the "new()" constraint". Any ideas? thanks for the input too!

Comment: updated, note the `new()` constraint on the function type `T`

Comment: Thank you, that worked pefectly. Appreciate the help!